# Why is the classpath order different when I run the application using bootRun vs java -jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a project created by using gradle.

There are two dependences within different version in the project, actually only the newer one will be used.

When I use `gradle:bootRun` to start the project, and when execute some method, there will be a crash problem, but when I use the `java -jar` to start the project and excute the code, there will be no problem.
Although I have solved the problem by excluding the older dependence, but still feel curious the difference between using `Java-jar` and `BootRun` to start a project.

The error is happening in running time.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: # 
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000105f230c2, pid=36963, tid=0x0000000000005f03
```

And the dependences i used are

```
compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.2.1' 
compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.8.2.1'
```

we have found the problem is because lz4 libraries in kafka conflict –

(I am sorry about my poor English, ask me if there is needed details about this problem )

Comment: Can you add the dependencies that are causing the problem, and the exact stacktrace of build error.

Comment: Thanks for comment.
the error is happening in running time.

# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000105f230c2, pid=36963, tid=0x0000000000005f03

And the dependences i used are 
compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.2.1'
compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.8.2.1'
we have found the problem is because lz4 libraries in kafka conflict

Comment: Please update this in your question, not in comments.